# Jmeter- Issue with POST request data having arabic characters

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am using Jmeter for performing performance testing, the issue I am facing is with the HTTP POST request .

I wanted to pass an Arabic word as a value in the POST Data, but when I see the Request using the View result tree I can see that the Arabic word is getting replaced by "????"

I have tried checking/unchecking the Encode checkbox from the Http request it doesnt works.

please let me know how can we take care of the same.

[image]

Comment: whats ur content encoding? try with `UTF-8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter - Simulate accented UTF8 characters in http POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233099/jmeter-simulate-accented-utf8-characters-in-http-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

Your content encoding is `US-ASCII`

Change your content encoding to `UTF-8` in your sampler and try