# Can we pass the arabic characters in Jmeter payload?

Tags: jmeter

It works with content - encode as "UTF-8", eg. "عيسى علي محمد البقالي", is converted to "Ø¹ÙŠØ³Ù‰ Ø¹Ù„ÙŠ Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ù‚Ø§Ù„ÙŠ"

Is there a way to make pass the content same as arabic in the payload?

Expected the payload to be in Arabic in Post request payload. Will the Jmeter allow it to pass arabic value in request payload?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JMeter - Simulate accented UTF8 characters in http POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233099/jmeter-simulate-accented-utf8-characters-in-http-post-request)  (provided that Arabic character show OK, when encoding in UTF8 )

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can

[image: d]

However you need to use the encoding which supports arabic characters or consider switching to [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) which supports pretty much everything including even [this one:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poop_emoji)

Add `file.encoding=UTF-8` to [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and restart JMeter. Once done you should see arabic characters in the payload.